# Down vote with describing reason

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I got some down votes recently. When someone gives me a down vote and describe his logic, somehow it helps me to get the point and improve. But sometimes no one said nothing and just gives a down vote. When, I couldn't find any reason behind the down vote, it feels frustrating. I know, when any use down vote any question or answer, there pop up a window and tells to describe the reason. But not every one takes it seriously. So, I though about it, if it can be mandatory to describe the reason of down voting, may be it will be good for users.

Answer (score 6):

If you provide links to your downvoted answers, we can probably try to find explanations.

Personally, I would not make it mandatory to write a reason for every downvote. Generally, I try to comment on my downvotes if I think there is a chance for improvement but some answers/questions should be downvoted as fast as possible and a mandatory essay is not going to help.

I can only recommend not to take a few scattered downvotes too seriously or personally.

Comment: Can you help me to find out the reason please:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48604/read-specific-column-and-row-value-from-a-text-file-using-python/48609#48609

Comment: @Emi I think the question was how to return the value 763. If that is the case, your answer does not match the question.

Comment: Ohh, then I just misunderstood the question. I thought he asked for 2nd last value of 2nd column of each raw. Then, I think, may be he should tell me that and I could make the answer right. Anyway, thanks